# Having a SQL command not properly ended when adding an alias

Tags: sql, oracle

So, I got a simple query, very basic, but I don't understant why, I got a `SQL command not properly ended error` when I have an alias for my query and, I don't understand why it does not work now, while it was working fine until today.

The query :

```
(select max(service) from t_post po  where po.id = 591 ) AS SERVICE;
```

And it works when the query is :

```
(select max(service) from t_post po  where po.id = 591 );
```

I really don't understand why, and plus, so sudden.

Comment: Oracle does not support the `AS` keyword for a table/query alias. Only for column aliases

Comment: Well, I can obviously do `select (select max(service) from t_post po  where po.id = 591 ) AS SERVICE from t_table`  . I was missing a parenthesis, now it is added, it works.

Comment: Well, that is a *column* alias not a (sub)query alias. Your first example looks like a sub-query due to the missing context in which you use it.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. As the subquery alone still give an error, my first though was the subquery was the problem, and don't copy the big query.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have any use for the alias. Try labeling the aggregated column value:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(po.service) AS SERVICE 
FROM 
    t_post po 
WHERE 
    po.id = 591
```

Comment: In fact, it is part of a bigger query, so I need my subquery (the one I write here), to be an alias, thats why I make a max, to have only one result. But I isolated the query, and got those problems.

Comment: If it's part of a bigger query... then you don't need the final semicolon

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(service) AS SERVICE from t_post po  where po.id = 591 ;
```

Comment: In fact, it is part of a bigger query, so I need my subquery (the one I write here), to be an alias, thats why I make a max, to have only one result. But I isolated the query, and got those problems.

Comment: @Zaphod The context ("bigger query" & how it is used) is very essential in solving the actual problem, please update the question.

Comment: @heikkim so, it means it's not really this query, but a problem with the bigger query. I will checked it.

Comment: @Zaphod Then take a look at a_horse_with_no_name comment under your question.

Comment: @valex I found the error in the big query, I was missing a right parenthesis, so my alias were not well interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the query in a from clause you must alias without the AS word. So It looks like, for instance:

```
select * from (select max(po.service) from  t_post po  where po.id = 591 ) SERVICE ....
```

And then you could refer the subquery as SERVICE.

I hope the answer it would be useful for you.